# iOS 7 (non-jailbreak) Wi-Fi RSSI value

Tags: ios, ios7, iphone-privateapi, rssi

Is it possible to get Wi-Fi RSSI value on non-jailbroken iOS 7 device? I read about MobileWiFi.framework and `Apple80211` functions and if I understand correct they don't work without jailbreak.

I don't want to publish my app on AppStore, so PrivateAPI is allowed.

Comment: I need wifi signal strength

Comment: did you get it? I tried MobileWiFi.framework without success http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the original post from where this was taken but it worked for me on a jailed device running iOS 7.1 (doesn't work on iOS 8):

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

-(NSDictionary *)currentWiFiInfo
{
   void *libHandle;
   void *airportHandle;

   int (*apple80211Open)(void *);
   int (*apple80211Bind)(void *, NSString *);
   int (*apple80211Close)(void *);
   int (*apple80211GetInfoCopy)(void *, CFDictionaryRef *);

   NSMutableDictionary *infoDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
   NSDictionary * tempDictionary;
   libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration", RTLD_LAZY);

   char *error;

   if (libHandle == NULL && (error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
      NSLog(@"%s", error);
   }

   apple80211Open = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Open");
   apple80211Bind = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211BindToInterface");
   apple80211Close = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211Close");
   apple80211GetInfoCopy = dlsym(libHandle, "Apple80211GetInfoCopy");

   apple80211Open(&airportHandle);
   apple80211Bind(airportHandle, @"en0");

   CFDictionaryRef info = NULL;

   apple80211GetInfoCopy(airportHandle, &info);

   tempDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)info;

   apple80211Close(airportHandle);

   [infoDict setObject:(tempDictionary[@"RSSI"])[@"RSSI_CTL_AGR"] ? (tempDictionary[@"RSSI"])[@"RSSI_CTL_AGR"] : @"0" forKey:@"RSSI"];
   [infoDict setObject:tempDictionary[@"BSSID"] ? tempDictionary[@"BSSID"] : @"null" forKey:@"BSSID"];
   [infoDict setObject:tempDictionary[@"SSID_STR"] ? tempDictionary[@"SSID_STR"] : @"null" forKey:@"SSID"];
   [infoDict setObject:tempDictionary[@"RATE"] ? tempDictionary[@"RATE"] : @"0" forKey:@"SPEED"];

   return infoDict;
}
```

Comment: @doxsi this worked for me on a jailed (non-jailbroken) device

Comment: Could you share the step you followed, please?