# How to use iOS CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo to read WIFI signal strength (RSSI)?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to get the signal strength of an iPHone's present WiFi connection.
(This is just a development experiment and not an app that will go to app store.)

I've searched CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo reference but can't see how to do it.

Needs to be for iOS 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to be App Store conform I see no way -- there is no public api for that

---

the answer here mentioned a C function that does what you want but it isn't public api: 
[Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk) 
**further info on how to use that function:**

[Accessing & Using the MobileWiFi.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018110/accessing-using-the-mobilewifi-framework)
NOTE: private api may break at any point and this might even be broken already anyways

`CCNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo` won't help you AFAIK -- you *CAN* misuse the captive networks API to get the current SSID but I don't see how it could get you the RSSI

Comment: It is not for App Store.  So, private API is ok.

Comment: great, then look at the 2nd link

Comment: But the 2nd link is all from 2010-2012 and out of date.  I'm going to try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259033/ios-7-non-jailbreak-wi-fi-rssi-value which as a solution that worked for iOS 7.1

Comment: So, this is the answer to the question:  CCNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo does not read RSSI.